# Coreplot Graph Scaling Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, graph, core-plot

I have two graphs which have variable range of X and Y values. 
The following graph-scaling  was attained of using the `scaleToFitPlots:(NSArray *)plots` method.

[image]

But my intention is to get the scaling look like following and I can't find any suitable method in CorePlot framework to accomplish it. Some pointers on it would be very appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already know the ranges you want displayed, skip calling `-scaleToFitPlots:` and set the `xRange` and `yRange` directly.